# Difference between width, height and implicitWidth/Height and corresponding use-cases in QML

Tags: qt, qml

What is the difference between `width/height` and `implicitWidth/Height` in QML? When should one set the implicit dimensions instead of the regular? When should one ask the implicit dimensions instead of the regular from a component/item?

Comment: Great question! I've been struggling with this for quite a bit too!

Comment: Excellent! Lot's of people struggle with this, when starting with QML.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Generally, usage of `implicitHeight/Width` only makes sense within reusable components.

It gives a hint, of the natural size of the Item without enforcing this size.

Let's take a `Image` as an example. The natural size of the image would map one pixel from the image file to one pixel on the screen. But it allows us to stretch it, so the size is not enforced and can be overridden.

Let's say now, we want to have a gallery with pictures of unknown dimension, and we don't want to grow but only shrink them if necessary. So we need to store the natural size of the image. That is, where the implicit height comes into play.

```
Image {
    width: Math.max(150, implicitWidth)
    height: Math.max(150, implicitHeight)
}
```

In custom components, you have a choice on how to define the sizes.

The one choice is, to have all dimensions relative to the components `root`-node, maybe like this:

```
Item {
    id: root
    Rectangle {
        width: root.width * 0.2
        height: root.height * 0.2
        color: 'red'
    }
    Rectangle {
        x: 0.2 * root.width
        y: 0.2 * root.height
        width: root.width * 0.8
        height: root.height * 0.8
        color: 'green'
    }
}
```

In this case, there is no natural size of the object. Everything works out perfectly for each size you set for the component.

On the other hand, you might have an object, that has a natural size - that happens, e.g. if you have *absolute values in it*

```
Item {
    id: root
    property alias model: repeater.model
    Repeater {
        id: repeater
        delegate: Rectangle {
            width: 100
            height: 100
            x: 102 * index
            y: 102 * index
        }
    }
}
```

In this example you should provide the user with information about the natural size, where the content does not protude the item. The user might still decide to set a smaller size and deal with the protrusion, e.g. by clipping it, but he needs the information about the natural size to make his decision.

In many cases, `childrenRect.height/width` is a good measure for the `implcitHeight/Width`, but there are examples, where this is not a good idea. - e.g. when the content of the item has `x: -500`.

A real life example is the `Flickable` that is specifically designed to contain larger objects than its own size. Having the size of the `Flickable` to be equal to the content would not be natural.

Also be careful, when using `scale` in custom components, as the childrenRect will not know about the scaling.

```
Item {
    id: root
    implicitWidth: child.width * child.scale
    implicitHeight: child.height * child.scale
    Rectangle {
        id: child
        width: 100
        height: 100
        scale: 3
        color: 'red'
    }
}
```

---

And to your comment: *I just don't understand why it is better to set implicitWidth/Height instead of setting width/height of a component's root dimension.*

> `implicitWidht/Height` are not a necessety - QtQuick could do without them. They exist for convenience and shall be convention.

---

**Rule of Thumb**

> When you want to set dimension of a root node of a reusable component, set `implicitWidth/Height`.
>   In some cases, set it for non-root-nodes, if the nodes are exposed as a property.
>   Do so only, if you have a reason for it (many official components come without any).
>   When you use a component, set `width/height`.

Comment: Thank you derM and Georg Schölly for your answers. I like this answer slightly more, because it has a bit more in depth explanation and +1 for the "Rule of Thumb". Also thanks for the answer for my comment. I was thinking something similar, that it is a good practice. Accepting this answer for now, but I hope there will be other posts/comments/discussions about this.

Comment: Very nice complete answer. The tag was lacking a good answer on this topic. :)

Comment: One important thing is missing in my opinion : the role of implicit size when you use the item in a layout, which is close to QWidgets/QLayout behaviour with sizeHint.

Comment: @ymoreau: I have not worked with the QtQuick.Layouts much, yet. I will investigate it and update the answer if necessary. Thanks for pointing me to this.

Comment: @derM Any updates when it comes to `Layout` types? Reading this doc it it seems that using `implicitX` over `x` makes sense in layouts as well:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquicklayouts-overview.html#specifying-preferred-size

Answer (score 9):

I don't have the definitive answer but I can tell you what I found out. First, [from the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#implicitWidth-prop):

> ## implicitWidth : real
>
> Defines the natural width or height of the Item if no width or height
>   is specified.
>
> The default implicit size for most items is 0x0, however some items
>   have an inherent implicit size which cannot be overridden, for
>   example, `Image` and `Text`.

but [less informative for width](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#width-prop):

> ## width
>
> Defines the item's position and size.

The `width` and `height` reflect the actual size of the item in the scene. The implicit size is some kind of inherent property of the item itself.<sup>1</sup>

I use them as follows: When I create a new item and it can be resized, I set an implicit size *inside* the object<sup>2</sup>. When I'm using the object, I often set the real size explicitly *from the outside*.

The implicit size of an object can be overridden by setting height and width.

## an example: TextWithBackground.qml

```
Item {
    implicitWidth: text.implicitWidth
    implicitHeight: text.implicitHeight
    // the rectangle will expand to the real size of the item
    Rectangle { anchors.fill: parent; color: "yellow" }
    Text { id: text; text: "Lorem ipsum dolor..." }
}
```

## an example: MyWindow.qml

```
Item {
    width: 400
    height: 300
    TextWithBackground {
         // half of the scene, but never smaller than its implicitWidth
         width: Math.max(parent.width / 2, implicitWidth)
         // the height of the element is equal to implicitHeight
         // because height is not explicitly set
    }
}
```

---

<sub>1) For some elements, like Text, the implicit height depends on the (not-implicit) width.

2) The implicit size usually depends on the implicit size of its children.</sub>

Comment: In short: implicit size is the space the object would like to occupy, size is the space it does actually occupy.

Comment: Note that for `Text`, `implicitWidth` is the width the text would occupy if there's no wrapping. `contentWidth` is the actual width of the `Item` if there is wrapping (it's equal to `implicitWidth` if there is no wrapping).

Comment: I think this is how I understood it as well. So in a nutshell use implicit dimension for "presetting" the dimensions of a component and use regular dimensions when you want to "overwrite" that. Implicit dimension is kind of like a fall back value if regular width/height isn't set. Am I making sense here?

Comment: @Silex: Yes, and also implicit width / height can be used when setting the explicit width / height.

Comment: From my experience, I came to the conclusion that you should use implicit size if you want to refer to a child size, and explicit size if you want to refer to a parent size. When creating a new component, don't hardcode the size, use implicit sizes instead. I tried to illustrate it in an example but momentarily gave up since it's hard finding a meaningful one :)

Comment: I just don't understand why it is better to set `implicitWidth/Height` instead of setting `width/height` of a component's root dimension. Setting the regular width/height would work the same way as fall back if I don't specify one where ever I create the given component.

Comment: I like your logic about children, parent and corresponding dimension usage @GrecKo though!

Comment: @Silex For example lets say you are the component user, you wouldn't be able to do `size: size * 2` (let's say for some reason you want to stretch the element twice its default size) But you can do `size: implicitSize * 2`

Answer (score 4):

Implicit size is supposed to be used when calculating size of an item based on its contents. Whereas setting `width` or `height` on a parent item may affect the size of its children it should never be a case, when you set implicit size.

**Rule of thumb**

> Implicit size should only "bubble up", i.e. children should never
>   lookup for implicit size of their parent to calculate their own
>   implicit size, neither parent should try to force implicit size of its
>   children.

If you would try to set `width` on a component similar to layout, that initially calculates its width from the `width` (rather than `implicitWidth`) of its child item and that child is affected by the size of a parent, you would end up with a binding loop.

This is why the property exists - to break cyclic dependencies when calculating size of an item based on its contents.

Comment: What if you want to create a resizable RowLayout that fills it's parent? Shouldn't you explicitly set the parents size and then have the elements of the layout be sized with respect to their parent (the layout)?

Comment: @pooya13 yes, you can set the size of the parent explicitly. Then the parent may set the size of its child explicitly. The question is how `RowLayout` should behave, if you don't set its size. If you won't set the size of the `RowLayout` neither use its attached properties`RowLayout` will use implicit size of children to calculate its own size.